# Interchange Children between two Layout<View>

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am developing in Xamarin for iOS, Android and UWP. I created a custom control called DragAndSwapContainer which implements two custom behaviors: DragBehavior and DropBehavior.

DragBehavior basically adds a PanGestureRecognizer to the View and emits an event when the View is being 'dragged' (and also translates the view according to the Pan done by the user). On the other side, DropBehavior listens to this events and emits other events when a View is passing over the container or when a View is dropped inside.

DragAndSwapContainer acts as a container that can receive other views, and as a draggable and droppable view at the same time. The goal of this container is to enable the user to swap between two views by dragging and dropping one into the other one.

When a View is dropped inside this Container what I do is, basically, to swap the Children Views that both containers have (the one with the view that was dragged, and the one receiving the dropped view).
Here's a piece of code for the DragAndSwapContainer (which inherits from Grid):

```
private void OnViewDroppedInside(object sender, DroppedEventArgs e)
{
    var draggedViewContainer = e.DroppedView.Parent as DragAndSwapContainer;

    draggedViewContainer.Children.Add(this.Children.First());
    this.Children.Add(e.DroppedView);
}
```

Since each View can have only one parent, this works fine: Child View is exchanged by the DragAndSwapContainers.

Everything works fine as respects to iOS and Windows, but I am facing some problems with Android.

I am getting the following error https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/8888 when swapping two views. After some debugging I conclude that the problem arises because while swapping children (in between the two lines of code of Children.Add) Android native renderers are disposed, so I lose track of the View.

Also it is something that doesn't happen always, seems that there's some timings issues. If I attach my Analytics service (which reports to a cloud server and adds some overhead) the issue happens way more often.

The error mentioned seems to be fixed in the Xamarin.Forms version I have (since it was merged already in v4.4.0) but I'm still having the exact same error call stacks.

Given this situation, is there another better way to exchange children between two Layout?

Comment: You could update the  XF to latest version (4.8.x)and test again. If the issue still exists , you could share the sample to github so that I can check it on my side .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I opened an issue in Github (https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/12867) where I add a reproduction sample

Comment: Ok , we will focus on it .

Comment: I had checked your sample , it works fine on my android simulator. By the way , drag and drop gesture recognizers are available now . You could check the doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/drag-and-drop .

Comment: Hi @LucasZhang-MSFT, it works fine until you add the UXCam analytics I mention in the post.

Yeah, I've seen the gesture recognizers, but they were experimental when I started coding this, so I've created my own